# Google Maps V2 setLocationSource removes blue MyLocation icon

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I'm working on an indoor GPS application and I have my own location provider that will give me lat and long.  I have google maps v2 working with my location provider by using

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.setLocationSource(myLocationProvider);
```

My problem is as I set the location source to my custom provider, the little blue icon that displays onscreen location no longer functions.  Is this expected?  Shouldn't google maps just use the lat/long to display the current location, no matter where it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

The blue dot should still be visible.

If you are sure your `LocationSource` is implemented properly, and after you call `OnLocationChangedListener` callback method the blue dot does not appear in the location you send, I suggest creating a simple working example to show the issue and post it on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

I would start with a test call in `activate`:

```
Location location = new Location("myProvider");
location.setLatitude(30.0);
location.setLongitude(30.0);
listener.onLocationChanged(location);
```